# Can't show value of jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to show the value of my slider it does not work?

```
<div class="hoogte hoogte2">
  <label for="kpa2_rating_value">Rating 2:</label>
  <div id="2" class="slider2" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
  €<input id="productprijs" type="text" class="kpa2_rating_value" name="kpa2_rating" value="0" style="border: none;" />
</div>
```

```js
$(".slider2").slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    $("#dom_element").text(value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The function you've defined does not have a `value` variable. Presuming you want to retrieve the value from the slider control you need to use `ui.value`, like this:

```js
$(".slider2").slider({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $("#dom_element").text(ui.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div class="hoogte hoogte2">
  <label for="kpa2_rating_value">Rating 2:</label>
  <div id="2" class="slider2" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
  €<input id="productprijs" type="text" class="kpa2_rating_value" name="kpa2_rating" value="0" style="border:none;" />
</div>
This is the script to show the value in an paragraph called
<p id="dom_element"><p>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend but i have a new question how do i store the value of the slider to a variable?

Comment: `var x = ui.value`. If you want that accessible to another function I'd suggest not putting it in a variable at all - read it directly from the slider where required: `$('.slider2').slider('value')`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$("#dom_element").text(value);
```

change it to:

```
$("#productprijs").val(ui.value);
```

In your case the **dom_element** is **productprijs** and for this element you need to use val instead of text method.

Moreover, you can use [slide( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) instead of change event.

```js
$( ".slider2" ).slider({
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#productprijs").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="hoogte hoogte2">
    <label for="kpa2_rating_value">Rating 2:</label>
    <div id="2" class="slider2" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
    €<input id="productprijs" type="text" class="kpa2_rating_value" name="kpa2_rating" value="0" style="border:none;" />
</div>
```